# How do I replace a special character

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding

I'm trying to replace a special character "Â½" with ".5"

**cell.InnerText="o208Â½-105u208Â½-109o208-110u209-110";**

```
                    string tempStr=cell.InnerText;
           
                    if (cell.InnerText.Contains("Â½"))
                    {
                        cell.InnerText.Replace("Â½", ".5");
                    }
                    string tempStr1 = cell.InnerText;
```

but my C# .Replace isn't working , I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is an immutable type. Compiler creates a new string after replacing. So try just this

```
var innerText = "o208Â½-105u208Â½-109o208-110u209-110";
innerText= innerText.Replace("Â½", ".5");
```

result

```
before  -  o208Â½-105u208Â½-109o208-110u209-110
after   -  o208.5-105u208.5-109o208-110u209-110
```